# Glassfish 4 Cookie Parsing Error

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, cookies, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 4 and Spring MVC to create a RESTful backend. The front end client can be of two types, a browser or a REST client (superagent in node.js). Things work fine form the browser.

However I am getting a weird exception when ever I try to send a request from an API based REST client (like superagent)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.CookieParserUtils.parseClientCookies(CookieParserUtils.java:353)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.CookieParserUtils.parseClientCookies(CookieParserUtils.java:336)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.Cookies.processClientCookies(Cookies.java:220)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.Cookies.get(Cookies.java:131)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.parseCookies(Request.java:1911)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.getCookies(Request.java:1505)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseSessionCookiesId(Request.java:4077)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tried my code with Glassfish 3 and everything works normal with all kinds of clients.

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When I send request with super agent, it somehow sets an empty cookie header. Like Cookie: ''
If I explicitly set the cookie value to something like Cookie: 'cook=ie', everything works.

I have opened an issue at superagent:

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/285

I am still unsure if this empty header is due to a bug in super agent or if there is some flaw in my code. But for now I am ok with the temporary fix.

Comment: Opened an [issue with glass fish community](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20887) as it seems to be a problem which should be fixed on glass fish after a discussion at super agent issues.